# Edit CSS variables like Sass and add custom rules inside Admin Panel in PHP / Laravel

Tags: php, css, laravel

What is the best practice for making css changes (like change a color variable in all website or adding custom rules) inside an Admin Panel in PHP/Laravel?

The ideia is give some customization options for the website's admin without need a programmer, so he could change the colors, font sizes and stuff like that.

This informations should be saved in database, but I don't like the ideia of make some `style.php` file to return the CSS. There is a tool for that? Or some better way to do it?

Comment: `I don't like the ideia of make some style.php file to return the CSS`.  Could you list the reasons why you don't like this idea?  I'd think isolating the things that can change inside of a php based stylesheet is a good solution here.  Caching would definitely be encouraged.  A better, but more limiting, solution may be to write stylesheets for each theme and only pull the theme name from the db.

Comment: At first glance, it seems not the right way to do it. The side of performance that I thought the will be bad will be optimized with cache, so will not be a problem anymore. Asking for a stylesheet with .php extension will not cause a "mess" in the browser? I was wondering a way of do it that only changes the CSS file when saved in Admin, this way we still have an .css file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with the comments made above.

What you could do, is if you are using SASS (you may be able to find a LESS equivalent) to compile your CSS then you could use [sass-json-vars](https://github.com/vigetlabs/sass-json-vars).

This way you could use PHP to manipulate a JSON file of colours that can be used within your SASS, then you can compile them  through the likes of NPM.

Comment: This could work, there is a way to run `npm run build` as a Cron job?

Comment: Depending on where you are, I’m assuming a model here. You could do something like `file_put_contents('PATH_TO_FILE', json_encode($colours, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT));` to save the variables and then `exec('npm run --prefix ' . __DIR__ . '/../ production');` to compile.

Comment: Did you manage to get this working?

Comment: Yeah, I didn't finish it, but I did some tests and I believe that this will work better than a `style.php` file, thanks